# Adding audio and controlling the volume dynamically in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to play an mp3 file and dim/increase the volume at certain points. I found a tutorial on how to add 3D sound, but that seems like overhead. Can I just load the mp3 file and somehow control the volume. Any suggestions for functions would be a big help.

Comment: Yeah you can play the MP3 file into an `AudioSource` and control the volume via `AudioSource.volume`. Or am I oversimplifying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Any Audio File imported into Unity is available from scripts as an Audio Clip instance, which is effectively just a container for the audio data. The clips must be used in conjunction with **AudioSource** and an **Audio Listener** in order to actually generate sound.
- When you attach your clip to an object in the game, it adds an AudioSource component to the object, which has **Volume, Pitch** and a numerous other properties.
- While a Source is playing, an Audio Listener can “hear” all sources within range, and the combination of those sources gives the sound that will actually be heard through the speakers. There can be only one **Audio Listener** in your scene, and this is usually attached to the **Main Camera**.

In short, you can use AudioSource.volume to control this:

```
AudioSource source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
source.volume = 0.1f; // 0.0-1.0, you can change this at runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

you can handle it by colliders with trigger checked.

```
void Awake()
{
    AudioSource source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
   if(other.tag == "point")
      source.volume = 0.1f;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
   if(other.tag == "point")
      source.volume = 1f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best served following [this unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/audio-and-sound-manager/). But basically you want to add an audio source to a gameobject and associate it with an audio manager. I usually set up my manager to handle several different sound types(background music, sound effects, ui sounds, etc). Then you can dynamically change a specific sound type's level and it'll affect all audio sources associated with it.